# Stringbuilder AppendLine is adding one new line too much

Tags: c#, visual-studio, append, qr-code, stringbuilder

I am trying to generate a QR Code with C# in Visual Studio...
For each Big Tag I created a class with the childTags... I override the ToString() function to use Stringbuilder and add each tag to it

```
class QRCdtrInf
{
    public string IBAN;
    public QRCdtr Cdtr;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(IBAN);
        sb.Append(Cdtr.ToString());
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

at the end there is a class QRData which takes all the Classes ToString and append it..

```
class QRData
{
    public QRHeader Header;
    public QRCdtrInf CdtrInf;
    public QRUltmtCdtr UltmtCdtr;
    public QRCcyAmt CcyAmt;
    public QRUltmtDbtr UltmtDbtr;
    public QRRmtInf RmtInf;
    public QRAltPmtInf AltPmtInf;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(Header.ToString());
        sb.Append(CdtrInf.ToString());
        sb.Append(UltmtCdtr.ToString());
        sb.Append(CcyAmt.ToString());
        sb.Append(UltmtDbtr.ToString());
        sb.Append(RmtInf.ToString());
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}
```

I then Send it to Encoding and when I scan it, I always get one line too much for each line..
I even tried Append(Enviroment.NewLine)... 
And I tried using only Append... then it writes everything in one line.
so either I am having all values in one line or between each value one CRLF too much

EDIT:
So the Output now with AppendLine is like this:

```
1
Empty Line
2
Empty Line
3
Empty Line
```

But I want it like this:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: So your question is: "How to add a new line between your data?"
Right?

Comment: @AdrianEfford See my EDIT:

Comment: Try: sb.Append("data \n"); Does it what you want?

Comment: @AdrianEfford Not all hero wear capes... Thank you very much... but do you know why AppendLine makes one extra and I had to use "\n" ?

Comment: You are welcome ! To be honest I'm not sure... I think its because of the override String method. Try to debbug inside but as I said I'm not sure why you are having this issue. Let me know if you find it out !!

Comment: I have posted an answer so other people can easily find the solution to this issue. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a line separator ("\n")

---

```
sb.Append(data.toString + "\n");
```